# Has the "hero" music ever previously been associated with Godzilla in this way?

Tags: soundtrack, monsterverse, godzilla, godzilla-king-of-monsters

The track Godzilla Main Title, from the Godzilla: King of the Monsters soundtrack, starts very dramatically, and changes into music from the original Godzilla ('54) movie. This music was originally credited to Akira Ifukube.

Through out the movie, the original music acts as a sort of "hero" music for Godzilla (used in Rebirth and Battle in Boston, for example).

I have only watched this, and the original Godzilla film. In the original, I believe the more heroic sounding music is associated with the human rescue forces, not the monster (Godzilla being an antagonist in that, and other movies I guess).

Has this piece of music actually been associated with the monster himself, in any of the previous films, in the same way as King of the Monsters uses it?

Comment: The song is usually used in the Godzilla movies and usually used to represent Godzilla when he appears in the scene. The songs are used as tribute to the monsters and to the original work in Godzilla: King of monsters 2019 movie. Just like the theme song used when Motha comes out of the waterfall, it's the same melody as the original. So,  yes, the song has been used in most if not all Godzilla movies when he comes out.  It is his theme song https://youtu.be/o6qAIaqK3_Q